# :after element doesn't show without content

Tags: css

I am not a master of CSS, but I was trying to make my own navigation bar with a similar style of the one Instagram app uses.

I was trying to make the little bar displayed in the bottom of the selected option with an `after` pseudo-element.

However, it only shows when I set the attribute `content` to any value, even `""`. If I get rid of the attribute, the bar doesn't show. Why is this happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/jfs0guoh/

Comment: you may use a box-shadow to get rid of the whole element: http://jsfiddle.net/jfs0guoh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it i *specified* this way.

The default value for `content` is `none`.

And http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content tells you:

> Values have the following meanings:
>
> **none**
>   The pseudo-element is not generated.